# How to get android.support.transition.Transition from android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity?

Tags: android, android-support-library, shared-element-transition

I'm looking methods `get`and `set` of `android.support.transition.Transition` for `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity`

It's present in `android.support.v17.leanback.transition.TransitionHelper.TransitionHelperVersionImpl#getSharedElementEnterTransition`, but how to get access to the method?

Comment: Are you looking to use getSharedElementEnterTransition method from Fragment?

Comment: @SHUJATMUNAWAR I'm looking for method `get` of `android.support.transition.Transition` from `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity`

Answer (score 0):

To get Transition object in AppCompatActivity you can use any of Transition's subclasses like **Slide,Fade,Explode** etc as your needs.

```
Transition transition =  new Slide(30);
```

OR

You can inflate from transition resource file.

```
Transition myTransition =
        TransitionInflater.from(this).
        inflateTransition(R.transition.my_transition);
```

where my_transiton is your transition resource file like this.

```
<fade xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

or can have multiple transition using transition set like this.

```
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:transitionOrdering="sequential">
    <fade android:fadingMode="fade_out" />
    <changeBounds />
    <fade android:fadingMode="fade_in" />
</transitionSet>
```

check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/) official doc for more details.